# How to verify that indexed type extends string?

Tags: typescript, generics, extends, keyof

let's say I have function `func` with 2 generic arguments

```
const func = <T extends {}, K extends keyof T>() => {};
```

and a type

```
interface Form {
  a: boolean;
  b: string;
}
```

then I can invoke them like so without any errors

```
func<Form, "a">();
func<Form, "b">();
```

Now I want func to accept only keys for which `T[K] = string`
In other words

```
func<Form, "a">(); // should fail
func<Form, "b">(); // should pass
```

My pseduo-typescript solution would be

```
const func = <T extends {}, K extends keyof T : where T[K] extends string>() => {};
```

but that of course doesn't go far. Is it even possible?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little helper type to get all the string types keys:

```
type StringKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]:
    T[K] extends string ? K : never
}[keyof T]

type Test = StringKeys<{ a: boolean, b: string, c: string }>
// type: 'b' | 'c'
```

This utility type maps over all property of `T`, and if the value type extends string the key name is preserved, and otherwise it is discarded as never.

Then you simply use that like:

```
interface Form {
  a: boolean;
  b: string;
}

const func = <T, K extends StringKeys<T>>() => {};

func<Form, "a">(); // error
func<Form, "b">(); // fine
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwNIRAZwDwBUA+KAXigG8BYAKCigG10oUoBrLAewDMp8BdAFw06dfIz5QIAD2ARkAE2xRsCFKigB+KEwFRkEAG4R4NAL712Ibrz40aKWfC4BDAMbQAYh3gBbCsKhnXQAjDg4AGwhnZABuAODdFSQ0OOpTO2pXDmQVKC4AV2RXUigCABptSRk5RVhVNEwcAkJCAAoASlJiclNUmgKi3C9fCoAiZ1G29pioAHpZyXh4b37C1yHvHzHgyY6Z+byUCCA)